# Excel Monthly planner template dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the Excel template for Monthly Personal planner, I can see that the dropdown for Months is assigned to a list (`List_Months`) under Data validation.
But I could not find where this list(`List_months`) is populated.

Is it some kind of predefined macro in excel ?

[image]

Also only months from `Feb` to `Sep` is being populated in the dropdown, `Jan`, `Oct`, `Nov` and `Dec` is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in list of months with that name.

To find out where that list is defined in your workbook, use the Name Manager on the Formulas tab on the ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it helped finding the source of that list.
There is a hidden sheet listing all the available values.